# Groovy - Split string to a FIFO queue

Tags: groovy

I'm still getting up to speed on the shortcuts that groovy has to offer.

Is there a shorter, 'groovier' way to acheive splitting a string to a FIFO queue?

Here's what I have currently:

```
String source
Queue<Character> chars = new LinkedList<Character>(Arrays.asList(source.value))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work?

```
Queue<Character> chars = source.value as Queue<Character>
```

(assuming `source.value` is a `String`)

Actually, I just tried this:

```
source = [ value:'hello' ]
Queue<Character> queue = source.value as Queue<Character>
println queue.class.name
```

And that prints out

```
String_delegateProxy
```

Where I would have expected `java.util.Queue`

The best working example I can come up with is:

```
Queue<Character> queue = new LinkedList<Character>( source.value as List )
```

As `LinkedList` implements the `Queue` interface

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I get this:  `org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Could not instantiate instance of: java.util.Queue. `

Comment: What version of Groovy?  Seems to work on the webconsole...and with 1.7.10 on my machine

Comment: Ah, maybe I need to update.  I'm using 1.7.7.  I'll try with 1.7.10

Comment: I've just tried this on 1.7.6 and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: I've posted an issue on the JIRA http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4763 to see if anyone can see why the original isn't working as I'd expect -- it may be my expectations are wrong ;-)

Comment: Thanks.  To clarify, `source` is a string, not a map.  Calling `value` on a String returns `char[]`.  Therefore, the solution works as just `new LinkedList<Character>(source as List)`.  I've updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

this is enough (String -> char[] -> LinkedList)

```
Queue<Character> chars = '1234'.chars as LinkedList
assert '1' == chars.remove()
assert '2' == chars.remove()
assert '3' == chars.remove()
assert '4' == chars.remove()
```

one thing about the previous comments.

casting anything to an interface creates a proxy in newer versions of groovy  (1.7+ perhaps? not sure). at least anything besides the commonly used 'as List' or 'as Set' conversions.

this proxy delegates the interface methods to the casted object with calls like `InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(delegate, 'remove', args)`.  see `DGM#asType(Object, Class<T>)` and `groovy.util.ProxyGenerator`.

the String_delegateProxy tim got is one of those proxies, created from casting a String to a Queue.